# Why does Microsoft SSMS syntax highlight the word "configuration"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

When using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17254.0 and it's query editor, I noticed that the word `configuration` is always syntax highlighted as a blue keyword. Even though it doesn't appear to be in the list of [Reserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Is this a keyword in some other SQL standard or has this been a keyword before? Is there any reason this should be highlighted with the same color as `SELECT` or `WHERE`?

[image: Example query with "configuration" highlighted]

I found similar question asking about other keywords, and they all seemed to have logical reasons, but couldn't find anything for this word.

Primary reason for this question is that I want to know if using this as a column name in queries without the the brace encapsulation `[configuration]` is completely safe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are both Reserved Keywords, and Keywords in SQL Server. `CONFIGURATION` is a keyword, but it isn't reserved. Just like `int` (for the datatype `int`), and other words, are a keyword , but you could still use it in a statement unquoted:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (int int,
                     date date,
                     char varchar(10),
                     last decimal(12,2),
                     first numeric(12,2),
                     system char(2));
```

Every single word there is a keyword of some kind (including `sample`), but only `CREATE` and `TABLE` are reserved. `char` is even a datatype and a function and isn't reserved, so you *could* have a nonsensical statement like `CONVERT(char,CHAR(Char))`, and every reference to "char" has a different meaning.

`CONFIGURATION` isn't a [future keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#future-keywords) either, so at this time, you would seem fine to use it.

Comment: Interesting, is there a list of SQL Server *Keywords* somewhere? There obviously is a use case for `int` and `date` etc. What's the use case for the `configuration` keyword?

Comment: @ruohola: to make `ALTER SERVER [SCOPED] CONFIGURATION` statements color nicely. T-SQL is a very "Englishy" language; if every word used in a statement somewhere was reserved, you'd have to do a lot more quoting. (Not that that's necessarily a bad thing...)

Comment: *"is there a list of SQL Server Keywords somewhere?"* not that I know of, no (not officially anyway). Someone may have compiled a list of them. The one's you need to avoid are those in the document you've already linked (personally, where you can, I'd suggest avoiding the Future one's too, so that someone doesn't break, but that's much harder to do without always referring, so is more a pipe dream).