# Why does SSMS highlight the word 'SELF' like a reserved word?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I was exploring the usages of self-linked servers I happened to name the self-link `self`, just like in the code example I was following. I noticed that the SQL Server Management Studio editor highlighted the word in blue, as though it were a reserved word, even though it is not in Microsoft's official [list of reserved keywords in T-SQL and ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql).

Does `self` have some predefined meaning in T-SQL - which would make it a bad choice of name for a self-link - or are there other reasons not to use this name for this purpose?

Normally I steer clear of using words as identifiers if they are even remotely suspected of being reserved words or having predefined meaning. However, for the name of a server self-link the highlighting as an a priori meaningful word could actually be seen as a bonus.

The SSMS version is 17.1, in case it matters.

Comment: Not all keywords are reserved keywords. `NAME` and `date` are keywords, for example, but you can use them without quoting for objects. The list of keywords is far larger than the list of reserved, but I don't believe it's published.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044348/why-does-microsoft-ssms-syntax-highlight-the-word-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044348/why-does-microsoft-ssms-syntax-highlight-the-word-configuration)

Comment: `SELF` Is a keyword in the phrase `EXECUTE AS SELF` for example.

Comment: Larnu, thanks - that was precisely the info I was looking for. Hence `SELF`is a keyword after all, but it is not *reserved*. If you write your answer as an answer then I can accept and upvote. ;-)

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко already linked to an answer I'd written some time ago on  the subject :)

Comment: Larnu, I realise that I should not have overloaded my question. Should I post a new question 'Is it OK to use SELF as name for a linked server' or should I let the current question stand, as I'm obviously not the only one who's interested?

Comment: The questions are pretty much the same here; effectivelly your end question is "Is `SELF` safe to use", to which the answer is "yes", as Keywords and Reserved Keywords are different.